# Ionic Files and Directories

Tags: file, cordova, directory, ionic-framework

I am new to this file operations using ionic. I've been searching for a lot and I have found some working codes, such as file explorer, but I do not understand how its working! I tried it on my own but its not working. 
This is my js:

```
    function showdata(){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);
    }

    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
        var tmpPath = "Ringtones";
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(tmpPath, {create: false, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess, fail);           
    }

    function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
        // Get a directory reader
        var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();

        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess,fail);
    }

    function readerSuccess(entries){
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) 
        {
            console.log(entries[i].name);
        }
    }

    function fail(error){
        alert(error.message);
    }
```

This is my html:

```
    <body ng-app="starter" class="platform-android platform-cordova                       platform-webview">
    <div class="card">
            <button onclick="showdata();">Click me</button>
    </div>
```

Can someone help me with my problem? I want to to be able to show all the files within a specific folder that is inside my sdcard(m testing in android), and open those files like mp3, video or image!

Comment: please have a look at this [link](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/ionic-file-browser-app) you will find the path of the file location

Comment: I have already tried that code, which I do not understand!! The path in that tutorial is downloads ,which I do not know how to change!! I need to select my own specific path...